# Not able to get all the id of an API from a function

Tags: javascript, html, function, api

I'm working on OMDB API. but I have an issue on getting the ID. I created a global variable of movieID and then I gave it the movie ID from API inside a first function and when I'm trying to get those ID's in other function I only get the last ID of MOVIES list that I get which is No.10.

```
const url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=';
const apiId = '&ap6465465454';
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const movieDtl = document.querySelector('.movie-detail');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var movieId = null;
let inputsearch;
let object;
let movieList;
let movieDetail;

input.addEventListener('keyup', getmovies);

function getmovies(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    inputsearch = input.value;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        getdatalist();
    }
   }
    xhr.open('GET', url + inputsearch + apiId, true);
    xhr.send();
 }
}

function getdatalist(){
    object = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    movieList = object.Search;
    movieList.forEach(function(e){
        movieId = e.imdbID;
        // if i console log here it gives me all the ID's what i want inside this forEach function // 
        console.log(movieId);
        let list = document.createElement('li');
        movieDetail = '<img src="'+e.Poster+'" alt="Poster"><h4>'+e.Title+'</h4><button>View More</button>';
        list.innerHTML = movieDetail;
        ul.appendChild(list);
    }) 
        // Here it just give me the last ID of search Result // 
         console.log(movieId);
         getdata();
}

function getdata(){
    let vwbtn = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');
    vwbtn.forEach(function(elem){
      elem.addEventListener('click', function(){

        // i want to get the id of each movie here when i click on selected button// 
        console.log(movieId);
      })
    })
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="search-div">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search movie">
</div>

<ul id="movie-showcase">
</ul>

<div class="movie-detail">

</div>
```

I asked here before but I didn't get the answer people suggested me to use LocalStorage and I tried it but it still stores the last ID. I don't know where am going wrong. I'm a new programmer and this is my first API Project so please if anybody can help it would be appreciated, and i have provided the API Key also so that anybody can check the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same variable all the time, thats why it only saves the last one.

lets first rename the variable to make more sense since we want to store an array of moviesId so ,

```
var moviesId = [];
```

here you want to store it as an array of all the movieIds you just fetch,

```
movieList.forEach(function(e){
    moviesId.push(e.imdbID);
```

in your getdata we call a function to print the things you need and we pass it the index

```
function getdata() {
    let vwbtn = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');
    vwbtn.forEach(function(elem, index){
      elem.addEventListener('click', printStuff.bind(null, index) );
    })
},
```

and finally the printStuff function that will show the information you need

```
function printStuff(index) {
    console.log(moviesId[index]);
}
```

There is a lot of ways to handle this problem, this is just one of them, feel free to disagree with me or point any problems you find

Comment: rule - hey buddy I am getting an Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined

Comment: @KinanAlamdar sorry , was going to use a for , then realized you were using the forEach and forgot to add the index there, it should work now

Comment: rule -  thank you very much, Brother, you just saved my life. this .bind actually is a new thing to me I need to learn about it, anyways your code works thanx again.